# How to get a proper cms link (with pretty url) from smarty in prestashop?

Tags: php, url-rewriting, smarty, prestashop

If I want to link to a cms page from a template with smarty, I currently use something like this:

```
{$link->getPageLink('cms',null,null,'id_cms=4')}
```

But that is going to generate a regular url (with query string), so if I activate pretty urls (url rewrite), it won't work. I analized the Link class but I can't find a way to generate a proper rewritten url. In fact, THERE IS a simple way:

```
{$link->getCMSLink(4)}
```

BUT, taking a look into Link::getCMSLink notes, I read that using an ID instead of a CMS object is deprecated. But from a template I don't have the cms object available.

Anyone had the same problem?

Comment: Why don't you create the link in the controller and assign it to a Smarty variable?

Comment: In this case wouldn't be a good idea. What I'm searching for is a 'proper' way to do it from a tpl. Passing the ID to getCMSLink just works and I'll use it for now, but it's deprecated. One other thing could be create a masking function on FrontController (keep in mind that I potentially need it on all controllers). I could then pass the ID to the masking function, create the cms object, and return the link by passing it to getCMSLink. That would be a simple and general solution. Still, it's really strange that there aren't any already.

Answer (score 1):

I found it really by "let's try if this one works".....

In PS1.6 you can get CMS object like:

```
$myCMS = new CMS( YOUR_CMS_ID );
```

If you want to use it in tpl, you have to define it in your controller e.g.:

```
$this->context->smarty->assign( "myCMS", $myCMS );
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution. I recently tested it for Prestashop v1.6 and v1.7

This code utilizes the method **getCMSLink** of the Link class. It is necessary to know the id_cms of the CMS Page, to create the object model.

```
$link = new Link();

$cmsPageObject = new CMS(
  $id_cms,
  $id_lang
);

// $cmsLink has the URL string.
$cmsLink = $link->getCMSLink(
  $cmsPageObject, 
  null,
  Configuration::get("PS_SSL_ENABLED") === "1", 
  $id_lang,
  null,
  null
);
```